# How to assign User_id to an item

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

So I have locker model which is just a basic scaffold

```
  def change
    create_table :lockers do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.integer :lockerNo
      t.string :wing
      t.string :sttatus
      t.string :comment

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and also a user model which is just basic devise.

I want users to be able to select a locker they want,

So I want to list all the lockers and then users click on Select button and then the locker gets assigned to the user i.e the locker_id updates to the current user

This is my controller

```
  before_action :set_locker, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /lockers
  # GET /lockers.json
  def index
    @lockers = Locker.all
  end

  # POST /lockers
  # POST /lockers.json
  def create
    @locker = Locker.new(locker_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @locker.save
        format.html { redirect_to @locker, notice: 'Locker was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @locker }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @locker.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /lockers/1
  # PATCH/PUT /lockers/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @locker.update(locker_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @locker, notice: 'Locker was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @locker }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @locker.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def assign_locker
    if @locker.sttatus = Available
      @locker = Locker.find(params[:id])
      @locker.user_id = current_user.id
      @locker.save
    end

    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private
    def set_locker
      @locker = Locker.find(params[:id])
    end

    def locker_params
      params.require(:locker).permit(:user_id, :lockerNo, :wing, :sttatus, :comment)
    end
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What have you done on your own so far? What do you need help figuring out? Can you add more code?

Answer (score -1):

Make a controller method for updating the locker with the current user.

Put /lockers/[locker_id]

```rb
def update
  locker = Locker.findById(params[:locker_id])
  locker.user = current_user

  if locker.save
    head 200
  else
    head 422
  end
end
```

That's really ugly code that makes a few assumptions... but is it not what you're trying to do?

Comment: This assumes a `belongs_to :user` on locker. And `findById` (even in its correct form `find_by_id`) has been deprecated since rails 4. But otherwise, yes, this is roughly the shape.

Comment: It is similar to what I am trying to do but how will my view look like?